# Finding modulus when all power of p are removed from N!

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

Given two integers $p$ and $N$. Let $m$ be number by $N!$ by max power of $p$ which divided $N!$.
We have to find $m$ mod $p$. How to solve this?

Comment: Is $p$ a prime number? If not, say if $p=12=2^2\cdot3$, what does "removing all powers of $p$ from $N!$ mean? Does it mean to remove all powers of both $2$ and $3$? Or only the highest power of $12$, so that after removal a proper divisor of 12 might remain in $N!$.

Comment: This is a question in IOPC 2013 being held on Codechef at present. Please refrain from asking questions like this during the contest. Its not in the spirit of the contest.

Comment: This looks difficult, even if $N\lt p$. One should be able to give an efficient algorithm, for smallish $p$ and large $N$.

Comment: @coffeemath Your last statement is right. Only the highest power of 12, so that after removal a proper divisor of 12 might remain in N!

Comment: @noob: I appreciate your concern. I have requested moderators to close down this question for now.

Comment: @noob: I have deleted my answer accordingly. Too bad, time wasted :-P

Comment: There is a formula that appears reasonable to me, I have written it as an answer, but then deleted it after I saw the post by @noob.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for asking but I tried much then asked. I have seen your solution before deletion. I have tried that but that helps to find the max power of p that divides N! but not the m mod p. We will discuss when you will post that later.

Comment: @Shashwat, I have checked numerically, and my formula stands. In my by now invisible answer I have also written the code to compute it. But rules I agree with do not allow me to talk about it. Will repost as soon as sensible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, it's not really difficult, the formula/algorithm requires essentially to write $N$ in base $p$. (I am not allowed to say more at this stage.)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: just undelete when the question is unlocked

Comment: @robjohn, will do!

Answer (score 2):

The [contest being over by now](http://www.codechef.com/IOPC2013/), here's my solution.

I assume, as in the [original problem](http://www.codechef.com/IOPC2013/problems/IOPC13O), that $p$ is a prime.

First you have the product of all $i \in \{1, \dots, N \}$ which are
coprime to $p$. Since $$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p},\tag{Wilson}$$ this
will be 
$$
(-1)^{a_0} \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot b_{0} \pmod{p}
$$
if $N = a_0 p + b_0$, with $0 \le b_0 < p$. Note that
$$
a_{0} = \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p} \right\rfloor.
$$

Then there is the contribution coming from all the numbers that are
divisible by $p$ but not $p^2$. If $$a_{0} = a_1 p + b_1$$ with $0 \le
b_1 < p$, then by (Wilson) they contribute 
$$
(-1)^{a_1} b_1! \pmod{p}.
$$
Then there are the terms divisible by $p^2$ but not $p^3$, etc.

All in all, it seems we get
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{\dots} (-1)^{a_i} b_i! \pmod{p},
$$
where 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{N}{p^i} \right\rfloor = a_i p + b_i$$ for $i \ge 0$, and $0 \le
b_i < p$, or, recursively, $N = a_0 p + b_0$, and then $a_{i-1} = a_i
p + b_i$ for $i \ge 1$, with $0 \le b_{i} < p$ for all $i \ge 0$. 
The $b_i$ are thus the coefficients of the representation of $N$
in base $p$. Note that in the product we stop with the $i$-th term
when first $a_i = 0$.

This is a [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) program to compute the result. For large $p$ one
should compute the factorial in a smarter way, at the very least with
intermediate reductions modulo $p$. *With this variation*, on my oldish machine the code appears to run in a competitive time with respect to the requirements of the problem.

```
function ( n, p )
    local  a, b, curr, res;
    curr := n;
    res := 1;
    while curr > 0  do
        a := EuclideanQuotient( curr, p );
        b := EuclideanRemainder( curr, p );
        res := res * (-1)^(a mod 2) * Factorial( b ) mod p;
        curr := a;
    od;
    return res;
end
```